# Why the other side of the plane is not being shown?

Tags: qt, opengl, 3d, qt5, blender

I created a plane in Blender and added it as a [QCustom3DItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcustom3ditem.html) on [Qt chart](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstract3dgraph.html#addCustomItem).

But while rotating the graph I noticed I can't see the other side of the plane, why?

[image]

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <Q3DBars>
#include <QCustom3DItem>

using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    resize(800,600);
    auto vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    auto graph = new Q3DBars;
    auto widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
    vLayout->addWidget(widget);

    auto bar = new QCustom3DItem;
    bar->setMeshFile(":mesh/planey.obj");
    bar->setScaling(QVector3D(.1f,.8f,.1f));

    graph->addCustomItem(bar);
}

# Blender v2.81 (sub 16) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o Plane
v 0.000000 2.000000 1.000000
v -0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v 0.000000 2.000000 -1.000000
v -0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vn 1.0000 -0.0000 0.0000
s off
f 2/1/1 3/2/1 1/3/1
f 2/1/1 4/4/1 3/2/1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because **face culling** occurs.

The renderer is set to show only the triangles whose normals are facing the direction of the camera. Triangles oriented the other way around are considered "back faces", and hence skipped for performance reasons.

Unfortunately, this seems to be hardcoded in Qt, as shown in class *abstract3drenderer.cpp*:

```
void Abstract3DRenderer::initializeOpenGL()
{
    m_context = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
    // Set OpenGL features
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    // ...
```

I'm not sure if you can override this since the 3D renderer is private.

One possible workaround is to provide an .obj file with two planes, one with normals facing one direction and the other with normals rotate 180°. Although this can create other problems such as Z-fighting...